# React - redux-form initialValues with draftjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, draftjs

I am trying to use [draft-js](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js) for Rich Text Editor in my app, with **redux-form**, the problem I am facing is I am not able to populate initialValues into the Editor from **draft-js**, my code looks like this

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit.bind(this))}>

  <Field
    name="websiteurl"
    placeholder="INSERT WEBSITE URL HERE"
    component={this.renderFieldText}
    mandatory='true'
  />

  <Field
    name="htmlcontent"
    placeholder="ENTER HTML CONTENT HERE"
    component={this.renderRichTextEditor}
  />
  <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit" className="pull-right" loading={this.state.loading}>Save</Button>

</form>


renderRichTextEditor(field){
   return (
      <RichTextEditor placeholder={field.placeholder}/>
   );
}

renderFieldText(field){
      var divClassName=`form-group ${(field.meta.touched && field.meta.error)?'has-danger':''}`;
      divClassName = `${divClassName} ${field.bsClass}`;
      return(
        <div className={divClassName}>
        <input
        className="form-control"
        type={field.type}
        placeholder={field.placeholder}
        {...field.input}
        />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

I have two fields `websiteurl` and `htmlcontent`, the component `websiteurl` gets populated with initialValues, but I am not getting how to do this with draft-js Editor which is implemented inside **RichTextEditor** component..

If anyone has achieved something like this, please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to create a separate component for the Rich Editor's "field component" in order to not muddy up the form component. Personal preference really.

```
<Field name="content" component={EditorField} />
```

Moving to the EditorField component...

```
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    // here we create the empty state 
    let editorState = EditorState.createEmpty();
    // if the redux-form field has a value
    if (props.input.value) {
    // convert the editorState to whatever you'd like
      editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromHTML(props.input.value));
    }
    // Set the editorState on the state
    this.state = {
      editorState,
    };  
  }
```

Write the onChange function

```
onChange = (editorState: Object) => {
   const { input } = this.props;
   // converting to the raw JSON on change
   input.onChange(convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent()));
   // Set it on the state
   this.setState({ editorState }); 
};
```

Now in the render function, go ahead and place your editor component. Pass the Redux Form input props, your onChange function and the editor state.

```
<Editor
    {...input}
    onEditorStateChange={this.onChange}
    editorState={editorState} />
```

Now you can set the initialValues like you normally would using redux-form without Draft-js.

Comment: This seems to be correct, I tried this but there is one problem, the constructor of the component is getting called before the initialValues are set into the component, how to handle this situation..